# Variable cannot be inside the function

Tags: javascript, html

Heyo, can some one explain to me why this code won't work if the variable 'white' is inside the function?

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var white = true;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (white) {
    body.style.backgroundColor="pink"; 
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor="white";  
  }   
  white = !white;
});
```

Comment: Do you understand variable scope?

Comment: It'll work but it'll be always defined as `true` on each click. So, most of function's code will never happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: If the variable declaration is inside of the function, every single time the function is run, it will initialize to `true`, so your `if(white)` will always evaluate to true. It will change it to false, and then drop out of the function, popping that function off of the call stack (and consequently wiping out your white variable). Then when the function is run again, it re-initializes to true, runs `if(white)` code, and rinse & repeat. If you declare the variable outside the function, it lives beyond the scope of the function, and therefore retains its true/false state and your code works

Comment: You actually mean variable white "declared" inside the function. Variables declaration, initialisation, assignment or evaluation are different things that you should know about variables.

Comment: Thank you for such quick answers, as well as links about the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var white = true;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (white) {
    body.style.backgroundColor="pink"; 
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor="white";  
  }   
  white = !white;
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

You change the global variable `white` and after function execution it will be `true` or `false`, so the function will trigger the color to another (if it was white, after click it will be pink and vise versa).

But in this case:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var white = true;
  if (white) {
    body.style.backgroundColor="pink"; 
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor="white";  
  }   
  white = !white;
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

All local function variables are removed after the function execution is finished. Your `white` variable is always `true` on function start, so the first `if` statement works every time (changes the background to pink only).